# systemd timer unit starts several other services

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have a systemd timer that starts an associated unit every 5 seconds. This works as expected
(it spams the log, but that's another issue) but it apparently also starts some other systemd
units, that normally shouldn't be started.
These are my unit files:

`/etc/system.d/system/make_temps.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Puts all the temperatures in one file

[Service]
LogLevelMax=6
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/make_temps
```

`/etc/systemd/system/make_temps.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for unit putting the temperatures in one file

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=0sec
OnUnitActiveSec=5sec
AccuracySec=500msec

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I use this to prepare a file for another program:
[thinkfan](https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan).
I provide this information just to be sure, although I do not think that it matters.

When I check my logs with journalctl, I get the following output:

```
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Wizard being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Dynamic Linker Cache being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Journal Catalog being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create System Users being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Update is Completed being skipped.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Starting Puts all the temperatures in one file...
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: make_temps.service: Succeeded.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 systemd[1]: Finished Puts all the temperatures in one file.
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=make_temps comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=make_temps comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1586198459.428:1369): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=make_temps comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success' 
Apr 06 20:40:59 t490 kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1586198459.428:1370): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=make_temps comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Why do the services
`systemd-firstboot.service`,
`systemd-fsck-root.service`,
`ldconfig.service`,
`systemd-boot-system-token.service`,
`systemd-hwdb-update.service`,
`systemd-journal-catalog-update.service`,
`systemd-machine-id-commit.service`,
`systemd-sysusers.service`,
`systemd-update-done.service`
get started?

I have to say that these messages do not appear every time, but almost every time.
The reason why I think that it is related, is that on my other systems these messages do not appear (as I do not use these units) and when I stop the timer unit, the other services don't
get triggered either.
I have no idea, why this is happening and would be very thankful for each hint.

I use Arch Linux on kernel `5.5.13-arch2-1` and my systemd version is:

`systemd 245 (245.4-2-arch)
+PAM +AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid`

If I can provide any other information or if this is not the correct place to post this, let me know.

Comment: How do you know that the services are now started?  It cannot be from the words "Condition check resulted in … being skipped", so how did you determine the statuses of the services?

Comment: Well maybe the word "started" is not correct, but "getting triggered" is better describing what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Arch Forums, maybe related - not a solution unless entropy problem, then maybe solution. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=253767

Comment: Thank you for this link, this looks very similar.

Comment: Compare https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/15401 .